# Bind a combobox to an excel named range

Tags: vb.net

I am new to VB.net, my experience is writing VBA. I have placed a combobox in sheet dsbPositionBoard and would like that combobox to be populated with data from a named range called PosBox.

I can do it easily with VBA, but I have no idea how to go about in with VB.net

Comment: I don't know if you're familiar with EPPlus? Check its link  http://epplus.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this in the excel app?

Comment: In that case I would advise you to stick with vba, you can create COM interop code in VB.net to work with excel, and as Edper suggests, you can do a lot from EPPlus, but if you're already in Excel why not just use vba?

Answer (score 0):

Usually I just do the same thing in VB.net as I do in VBA except that in .net I have to start Excel first. Can you post some code? I assume you already know how to bind to Excel application from vb.net.